# eventqueue meaning of arrow

Tags: java, methods, syntax, eventqueue

because I couldn't find anything in google that would explain that, I decided to turn myself to ask you what the arrow in this specific example does, I never saw that expression so I don't really get it what it does.

Site I try to learn from: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/basics/

Thanks for helping!~

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Application ex = new Application();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which is a shorthand for defining functions. This creates a class with a method that takes no arguments and executes the statement block.

```
() -> {
    Application ex = new Application();
    ex.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look it up and thanks for the short explenation, it already made it easier to read through! ~

Comment: Okay I guess I get it, by anonymous you mean they are public but not accessible from outside (kinda private) since there is no name to call it from other classes.

Comment: It's similar to an anonymous class: `() -> some.function(call)` is shorthand for `new Runnable() {@Override void run() {some.function(call);}`, or whatever actual type the expression requires.